# Providing a file as input to a python script using cat in Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, redhat

I am trying to run a mapper script example written in python following the blog by Michael Noll here,
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

The command is:

```
cat /home/hduser/WorcountExample/pg4300.txt | /home/hduser/mapper.py
```

This command works fine on ubuntu 12.04LTS terminal. While trying to replicate it on a Red Hat Linux server, it gives the `error : No such file or directory`

Just wanted to know if I need to use a different command on Red Hat. Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you execute `cat /home/hduser/WorcountExample/pg4300.txt` on your Red Hat Linux server?

Comment: That works..it lists the contents of the file

Comment: It should work, of course. Ok, the next question is probably “What happens when you execute `cat /home/hduser/mapper.py` on Red Hat?” =).

Comment: that works too. It lists the mapper.py script. Both of them seem to be working individually.

Comment: Could you please show the whole error printed?

Comment: It's just the error I mentioned..`[hduser@shlpfatpt001 ~]$ cat /home/hduser/WorcountExample/pg4300.txt | /home/hduser/mapper.py
: No such file or directory`

Comment: How does the shebang line (first line) of `/home/hduser/mapper.py` read?

Comment: @Nitin this error is not looking fine… It should have an interpreter name and offending file name…

Comment: No need for `cat`. Just do `python /home/hduser/mapper.py < ./WordcountExample/pg4300.txt`. It might not be executable.

Comment: The shebang line is: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: What python interpreter is the first line of mapper.py pointing at? I guess that that's what the kernel can't find.

Comment: @squiguy It gives the same result

Comment: Try running `/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @1_CR running /usr/bin/env python starts the python console..    `Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2012, 14:23:48)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

Comment: phew....what does `file /home/hduser/mapper.py` report

Comment: @1_CR `/home/hduser/mapper.py: a /usr/bin/env python\015 script text executable
`

Comment: run `dos2unix` on `/home/hduser/mapper.py`, this should fix it

Comment: @1_CR Thanks! It works now. Could you explain why this error occurs?

Comment: `home/hduser/mapper.py` had `CRLF` line terminators, which must have thrown off the program loader attempting to interpret the shebang line. Anyways, badiya, lage raho!